# ObjectOutputStream and Jtable mouseClick setting

Tags: java, swing, io, jtable, objectoutputstream

```
 public class Excel01 extends JFrame{
      public static JTable table = new JTable();

     public Excel01() {
         table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener().........


    }
      class PopUp extends JPopupMenu.....
      class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener
        public static void main(String[] args) {
         Excel01 ex  = new Excel01(); 
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
         oos.writeObject(obj);

     }

 }
```

I did not include the whole code. but I will explain what I did.
as you see I create the class "Excel01" with JFrame extension.

and I made this Excel01 as Object file. and send it to the client whoever connected to my Server.

My question is
1. on client side. pop-up Jtable was successful. and also Server's data
   but Excel01's table's mouse click event setting was not working on client side.

I'm not really sure what this ObjectoutputStream outputting. If I want to send my mouse event what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are dramatically **over-burdening** yourself with way too many concepts that have **nothing** to do with each other.

If you intend to make any progress, you need to **dissect** those things into the real parts in there:

- An ObjectOutputStream is used to *write* java Objects to (read about [Java serialization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) here)
- A Mouse Event is a UI related "signal" ... there is simply no point in sending **that** to some remote server

In other words: you should step back and first learn about these different concepts that you intend to use. And then, when you understand the *parts*, try to use them to solve your problem.

It seems that you want to tell your "server" about something that the client does. Then the answer is **not** to give the server "the same UI components" and send mouse events there. Then the answer is clearly define the "data" the client is interacting with; and the potential actions one can perform using this client.

And then you define a distinct **protocol** between client and server; for example some way to send "commands" from the client to the server. The server receives commands, and does something about that.

Example:

- when your client starts, it might ask the server "send me the data to display"
- server sends that data, in an efficient manner (could just be serialized java lists, but could also be something else)
- User works with the client, for example he changes the values within a row
- Client can now: pre-validate the changes
- Send a request to the server "update value[x,y]"
- Server comes back "yes worked" or "no, failed" (then the client could give the user a error message)

Comment: is there any way to send the UN related"signal" to other?

Comment: See the update I just put in my answer. It took me a while to understand what you want to do. And you are doing the wrong thing ;-)

Comment: your Protocol mean I should send "data" to clients and use that data to performed the same action as Server?

Comment: What I am saying is: sending around JFrames doesn't sound like a good idea. And of course: certain work is done on the client side. Gonna update my answer again ... gimme two minutes.

Comment: yes, I was not sure what "ObjectStream" is sending exactly.
I guess It does not send the events and also functions.
that was my question

Comment: It is an **object** stream. It sends those **objects** that you put into it. But again: the key thing is that there is **always** a protocol required in a client/server setup. You really should focus on that part: understand what the client needs to do, **then** design reasonable **services** offered by your server to enable that (and that part includes to define what kind of data is sent from A to B). And as said: UI elements are UI elements, they make a very poor base for defining a protocol.